# ionic v2 webpack loader not loading json dependencies

Tags: typescript, webpack, ionic2, ethereum

We're porting a app prototype from ionic to ionic2 by cloning the [ionic-conference-app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app), which runs fine locally.

We're now trying to build a wrapper class to Ethereum JS wrapper library we have. The simplest way to reproduce the error is by adding a new class to the ionic-conference-app in `src/services/ethereum-service.ts`

```
import eth from 'ethereumjs-util';

export default class EthereumService {
  constructor() {}

  sha3() : Object {
    return eth.sha3("12345454");
  }
}
```

and then in some component, for example the About page in `src/pages/about/about.ts` adding the following

```
export class AboutPage {
  private ethereum : EthereumService;

  constructor() {
    this.ethereum = new EthereumService();
  }
}
```

Everything compiles happily with no errors in terminal that ran `npm run ionic:serve`. But the app doesn't load with the following error message in the console.

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./messages.json" /Users/my.name/my-app/node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:4 
>   at webpackMissingModule
>   ...

And if we look more closely into secp256k1 dependency, we see it fails at loading the following line.

```
var messages = require('./messages.json')
```

We've attempted to add the [webpack/json-loader](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) as a dependency to `package.json`.

We're using `"@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.44"`.

How can I get this dependency to be imported correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teammate figured it out. It was solved by updating to `"@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.46"` in `package.json`.